# Min Instance Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance, google-cloud-run, stress-testing

What if I set my `minimum instance` to 1, 4, 10. What is the difference between minimum instances 1, 4, and 10?
I'm curious about this one, because when I stress testing it. I didn't see any difference from this?

Is it only effect only in first-time HTTP Request?

Comment: You can have a look to your billing also! Having 1 or 10 doesn't cost the same!

Comment: Min instances will affect the cold start time for the first request that starts an instance. The performance of requests will not be affected once the container is warm. I use minimum instance count for services that need to respond quickly but do not receive request frequently enough to keep the instance warm. Once you reach the limits of simultaneous request for one instance, then you will have a cold start while the second instance starts. Therefore the answer depends on your traffic patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be good explained in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances):

> By default, Cloud Run scales in to the number of instances based on
> the number of incoming requests. However, if your service requires
> reduced latency and you want to limit the number of cold starts, you
> can change this default behavior by specifying a minimum number of
> container instances to be kept warm and ready to serve requests.

So, this is important to avoid cold starts when new instance is created. The maximum performance tested in stress testing should be on the same level.